# Date formatting in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I am just new to the MYSQL. In my insert statement, I have date format like `2018-05-26`. 
But while running a query I want to change in mm/yyyy. I have done the following

```
SELECT Number,Brand, FORMAT(DateofExpiration, 'mm/yyyy') AS DateOfExpiration 
FROM CreditCards WHERE [Name]='Victor Cerman';
```

but while doing this, the month is displaying **00**.

Comment: MySQL <> TSQL. What are you using ?

Comment: What data type is dateofexpiration?

Answer (score 0):

To format date, we would use [`Date_Format()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function in the MySQL.

So, **mm/yyyy** would be: `'%m/%Y'`. In **MySQL**, you would do the following:

```
SELECT Number,
       Brand, 
       DATE_FORMAT(DateOfExpiration, '%m/%Y') AS DateOfExpiration
FROM CreditCards 
WHERE Name = 'Victor Cerman';
```

Details:

- `%m`     Month, numeric (00..12)
- `%Y`     Year, numeric, four digits

You can see complete list of avaiailable format specifiers here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format